# AttributeError on successful redirection in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Redirection on successful POST request from Host View.

```
def product_page_view(request, prod_slug, color=None, size=None):
    ...
    ...
    prod            = Product.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug).first()
    seller          = prod.seller
    ...
    ....
    order_form = Buy_now_form()
    if request.method == "POST":
        order_form = Buy_now_form(request.POST)

        if order_form.is_valid():
            # Function for processing POST request and return order 
            order = buy_now_view(request, prod.slug, color, size)
            # Redirection 
            return redirect(reverse('product-shipping', kwargs={'order_id':order.order_id}))
    ...
```

url's of Host view and Target View are

```
    ...
    path('products/<slug:prod_slug>/<str:color>/<str:size>/', product_page_view, name="product-page-view-color-size"),
    path('products/<int:order_id>/shipping/', shipping_view, name="product-shipping"),
    ...
```

Though, function is redirecting successfully, but with AttributeError and following traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dixitgpta/byghouz/byghouz_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/dixitgpta/byghouz/byghouz_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/dixitgpta/byghouz/byghouz_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dixitgpta/byghouz/project/products/views.py", line 575, in product_page_view
    seller          = prod.seller

Exception Type: AttributeError at /products/54795882652377/shipping/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seller'
```

Product model :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(BygSeller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short_descrition = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=' ')
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    step1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    step2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    step3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    step4 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    step5 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    step6 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    step7 = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My target Redirected View is :

```
def shipping_view(request, order_id):
    customer = Customer.objects.filter(usr=request.user).first()
    order = Order.objects.filter(order_id=order_id).first()
    ...
```

[Traceback on TargetView after successful redirection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ytxw.png) (in case anyone finds it useful).

**Problem is** : ***After redirection***, traceback says that `prod is None`, howerver `prod` belongs to the `product_page_view` and I didnt get the idea of callback_kwargs. Values passed to the *prod_slug in callback_kwargs*(as the traceback says) is `order_id`, it belongs to the `shipping_view`. Also,

Why is callback function `product_page_view`? Shouldn't it be `Shipping_view`?

Thanks.

Comment: please share your **Product** models.

Comment: kindly check @DevangHingu

Comment: check if you are receiving a proper response from this line (make sure it is not empty object) `Product.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug).first()`

Comment: Yes, It does have at least One response to render. Also the issue is mostly with the redirected view. I have shared a scrnshot of traceback(if it could help). @ansuman

Comment: i think the problem is with `prod`. as you can seen in the local vars in your stack trace, it lists `prod` as `None` hence this error, Try to get product by changing to `Product.objects.get(slug=prod_slug)`

Comment: Heyy @ansuman I think, I didn't describe the question pretty well. I am sorry for that, But I have tried to provide a better description. Hope it helps you to understand my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should not use `first()` directly with `filter()` method. there is no record(data), It will return None. so None object has no any attribute **seller**

> you can use filter method like this

```
...
...
products = Product.objects.filter(slug = prod_slug)
if products.exists():  # True if any record available
     prod = products.first() 
     seller = prod.seller # please try print(seller) after that to check first record

...
...
```

make sure you have attribute **seller** in models. and your models contains **atleast 1 record**.
Also you can use count() method which return how many row it contains.

if it works, please let me know.

Comment: when your models contains 1 or more then 1 record your -> `Product.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug).first()` will work

Comment: The issue is mostly with the redirected view. I have shared a scrnshot of traceback(if it could help). Thanks

Comment: @dixitgpta but error showing that  it has problem with prod variable which get none type object. Thnks

Comment: Heyy Devang, I have improved my question. Hope it helps you to better understand my issue. Thanks