# django view not redirecting

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have two functions `product_page_view` and `buy_now_view`.

**Problem is**, after successfully posting `order_form`. `buy_now_view` is returning back to `product_page_view` without redirecting, if I do it like this :

```
def product_page_view(request, prod_slug, color=None, size=None):
    ...
    ...
    order_form = Buy_now_form()
    if request.method == "POST":
        order_form = Buy_now_form(request.POST)

        if order_form.is_valid():
            buy_now_view(request, prod_slug, color, size)
    ...
    ...
 

def buy_now_view(request, prod_slug, color, size):
    ...
    ...
    return redirect(reverse("product-shipping", args=(order_id,)))


def shipping_view(request, order_id):
    ...
```

And if i do it like this:

```
def buy_now_view(request, prod_slug, color, size):
    ...
    ...
    return order_id


def product_page_view(request, prod_slug, color=None, size=None):
    ...
    ...
    order_form = Buy_now_form()
    if request.method == "POST":
        order_form = Buy_now_form(request.POST)

        if order_form.is_valid():
            order_id = buy_now_view(request, prod_slug, color, size)
            return redirect(reverse("product-shipping", args=(order_id,)))
    ...
    ...


def shipping_view(request, order_id):
    ...
```

It gives me unwanted results. [Link to the Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849045/attributeerror-on-successful-redirection-in-django)

My URL's are:

```
# INDIVIDUAL PRODUCT VIEW PAGE COLOR & SIZE
    path('products/<slug:prod_slug>/<str:color>/<str:size>/', product_page_view, name="product-page-view-color-size"),

# INDIVIDUAL PRODUCT VIEW PAGE SIZE
    path('products/<slug:prod_slug>/<str:size>/', product_page_view, name="product-page-view-size"),

# INDIVIDUAL PRODUCT VIEW PAGE COLOR
    path('products/<slug:prod_slug>/<str:color>/', product_page_view, name="product-page-view-color"),

# INDIVIDUAL PRODUCT VIEW PAGE
    path('products/<slug:prod_slug>/', product_page_view, name="product-page-view"),

# SHIPPING VIEW
    path('products/<int:order_id>/shipping/', shipping_view, name="product-shipping"),
```

product_page_view :

```
def product_page_view(request, prod_slug, color=None, size=None):

    order_form = Buy_now_form()
      if request.method == "POST":
          order_form = Buy_now_form(request.POST)

          if order_form.is_valid():
              order_id = buy_now_view(request, prod_slug, color, size)
              return redirect(reverse('product-shipping', args=(order_id,)))

    prod            = Product.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug).first()
    seller          = prod.seller
    
    step_vital_info = Vital_info.objects.filter(product=prod).first()
    step_variation  = Product_variation.objects.filter(product=prod)
    step_offer      = Offer.objects.filter(product=prod).first()
    step_images     = Images.objects.filter(product=prod).first()
    step_desc       = Description.objects.filter(product=prod).first()

    variation_theme = {}
    variation_theme_img = {}
    var_prod_color = set()
    for i in step_variation:
        variation_theme.setdefault(i.color, []).append(i.size)
        var_prod_color.add(i.color)
        variation_theme_img.setdefault(i.color, []).append(i.var_image)

    if step_offer.sale_price:
        offer_price = step_offer.price
        discount = round(((offer_price - step_offer.sale_price)/offer_price) * 100)

    query_form = Query_Form()

    queries = {}
    query_ques = Query.objects.filter(product=prod) 
    for i in query_ques:
        queries.setdefault(i, []).append(Query_ans.objects.filter(question=i).first())    
        queries.setdefault(i, []).append(Vote.objects.filter(question=i).first())    


    return render(r...
```

What is happening here, exactly?

Comment: Can you add your urls.py also. And explain where is your page redirected after the action.

Comment: thanks for your time @Pax . I have added URL's and `product_page_view` is meant to be redirected to `shipping_view`. I have mentioned two cases above both having different issues with redirection .

Comment: Have you written an `app_name` variable in urls.py?

Comment: I am actually not aware how to do that. Would you please share some details? Thanks.

Comment: Well its actually a convention in django. If you haven't used `app_name` then this might not be the solution to your problem.
Suppose you have 2 apps and both have path set with `name="home"`. If you try to redirect to `home` URLConf will get confused on which home to go. So if we defined `app_name="App1"`. You can tell django which page to redirect by saying `redirect("App1:home")`. Incase you have defined app_name. Its necessary to keep app_name:name to redirect.

Comment: You might be using if else conditions in buy_now_view. If you can show all, I might be able to help you. If not, try a `print("I AM HERE")` function just before the `return redirect`. If the text doesn't appear to be printed on your console. It might be issue in your program logic.

Comment: Thanks @Pax for sharing such useful info. But, I think the issue might be with `product_page_view`, because if i try to apply the same logic of `buy_now_view` with other views, it works fine. Therefore, I am sharing my `product_page_view`.

Comment: Are you sure, the **order_form** is valid?

Comment: Yes @Pax , `order_form` is valid, because if i happen to put on a `print("I AM HERE")`(as you suggested), it does print it out.

Comment: I have posted the solution in answer. Please try that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you forgot to return the redirect request from **product_page_view**. The `buy_now_view` has returned the redirect request to `product_page_view`. Now it order to redirect, the `product_page_view` must also return the value.

```
def product_page_view(request, prod_slug, color=None, size=None):
    ...
    ...
    order_form = Buy_now_form()
    if request.method == "POST":
        order_form = Buy_now_form(request.POST)

        if order_form.is_valid():
            return buy_now_view(request, prod_slug, color, size)
```

Comment: I tried `return buy_now_view(request, prod_slug, color, size)`, but didn't work.